# Using macro variables with Lua in ConTeXt

Tags: macros, context, lua

I need to make some macros in ConTeXt. I have tried to use Lua code, but I do not understand how to mix ConTeXt source and Lua source together. Here is an example:

```
\define[3]\textmacro{
    \startlua
            if #1=1 then
                tex.print('#2')
            else
                tex.print('\math{#3}')
            end
    \stoplua
}
\starttext
    \textmacro{1}{This is some text.}{1+2}
\stoptext
```

If `#1` is equal to "1", this should print the contents of `#2`, otherwise it should print the contents of `#3` in math mode. In LaTeX, this can be written in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\textmacro}[3]{
    \ifnumequal{#1}{1}{#2}{$#3$}
}
\begin{document}
    \textmacro{1}{This is some text.}{1+2}
\end{document}
```

How can I do this correctly with Lua and ConTeXt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although Joseph has already answered your question, let me give a few alternatives.

#### The vanilla ConTeXt version

Note that you don't need to go to Lua just to do simple comparisons. Like LaTeX, ConTeXt provides simple comparison macros at the TeX end:

```
\define[3]\testmacro
    {\doifelse{#1}{1}{#2}{\math{#3}}
```

#### Using Lua in a TeX macro

Joseph gave one way to use Lua in a TeX macro. Another alternative is to use the Lua function (defined in ConTeXt) `commands.doifelse`. ConTeXt also provides the macro `\ctxcommands` to call functions in the `commands` namespace, so you can use:

```
\define[3]\testmacro
    {\ctxcommand{doifelse(1==#1)}{#2}{\math{#3}}}
```

Notice that I just do the comparison in Lua, and then pass the control back to TeX.

#### Defining a Lua function and calling it from TeX

If you have a more complicated function, the usual idea is to define the function in Lua and then call it from TeX:

```
\startluacode
  userdata = userdata or {}
  function userdata.testmacro(counter, text, math) 
      if counter == 1 then
        context(text)
      else
        context.math(math)
      end
  end
\stopluacode

\unprotect
\define[3]\testmacro
    {\ctxlua{userdata.testmacro(#1, \!!bs #2 \!!es, \!!bs #3 \!!es)}}
\protect
```

Note that I define the Lua function in the `userdata` namespace so that it doesn't pollute the global namespace. While calling the function from TeX, I use `\!!bs .. \!!es` to escape strings rather than `"..."`. This allows you to use `"` in the function argument, for example, you can call:

```
\textmacro{1}{"Hello"}{E^2}
```

and `"Hello"` will be printed.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things wrong. First, Lua uses the C-like `==` for comparison, not `=` (which is used for assignment). Secondly, you need to correctly escape the `\\` in the branch using `\math`. Finally, you want `"..."` to quote material. Also, as this is ConTeXt-specific we can use `context` rather than `tex.print`:

```
\define[3]\textmacro{
    \startlua
            if #1==1 then
                context("#2")
            else
                context("\\math{#3}")
            end
    \stoplua
}
\starttext
    \textmacro{1}{This is some text.}{1+2}
\stoptext
```

(Note: I'm no ConTeXt or Lua expert, so there may be more to add here!)

Comment: Or better `context.math("#3")` and so no backslash escaping is needed, see [ConTeXt Lua Documents](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/cld) documentation for more info.