# ConTeXt: Retain ToC Hyperlinks using alternative command

Tags: table-of-contents, context, context-mkiv

## Background

A custom Table of Contents entry was [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157054/2148) to move page numbers from the right-hand side to the left-hand side.

## Problem

The custom command loses ToC hyperlinks. I have tried to restore the hyperlinks as follows:

```
\goto{#3}[page(\currentlistentrylocation)]
```

This does not produce the correct page number link. Similar attempts include:

- \goto{#3}[#3]
- \gotopage{#3}
- \goto{#3}[page(#3)]

It seems that these commands cannot reference a page number indirectly.

## Code

Minimal example:

```
\setupinteraction[state=start,]
\setupcombinedlist[content][interaction=all,]

% Set the page number to the left of the section title.
\define[3]\SectionToCEntry{%
  \par \leftaligned\bgroup
    \hbox to 2em{\goto{#3}[page(\currentlistentrylocation)]}%
      \hskip 1em
      \vtop{\hsize\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax#2}
  \egroup \par%
}

\setuplist[section][
  alternative=command,
  command=\SectionToCEntry,
]

\starttext
  \placecontent
  \dorecurse{4}{
    \page
    \section[title={Section A}]
    \dorecurse{5}{\input knuth}
    \section[title={Section B}]
    \dorecurse{5}{\input ward}
  }
\stoptext
```

## Question

I am wondering:

- how would you retain the internal hyperlinks for such a custom ToC; or
- is there a simpler approach to reconfiguring the ToC?

## Related

Additional information:

- http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/strc-ref.mkvi
- http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/goto

Comment: You can wrap the entry in [`\hbox \strc_lists_get_reference_attribute\v!all`](https://github.com/mpfusion/context-slide/blob/master/t-slide.mkvi#L315-L318)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alternative=interactive` as per Wolfgang's solution (from the mailing list):

```
% Set the page number to the left of the section title.
\define[3]\SectionToCEntry{%
  \leftaligned\bgroup
    \hbox to 2em{#3}%
      \hskip 1em
      \vtop{\hsize\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax#2}
  \egroup 
}

\setuplist[section][
  alternative=interactive,
  command=\SectionToCEntry,
]
```

Marco's solution is slightly more complicated:

```
\unprotect
\define[3]\SectionToCEntry{%
  \hbox \strc_lists_get_reference_attribute\v!all{%
    \par \leftaligned\bgroup
      \hbox to 2em{#3}%
        \hskip 1em
        \vtop{\hsize\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax#2}
    \egroup \par%
  }
}
\protect
```

The `\unprotect` is required to accommodate for `\v!all`.